# Why does the heading “The Sentence” use the article?

Tags: grammar, articles

> *THE SENTENCE*

Why does the Book 1 Grammar chapter 1 heading use the definite article "the"?
See the page number 10

The page[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bclo2.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bclo2.png)

Comment: This is "generic the"  see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/the-generic-use-of-the and probably other questions/answers.

Comment: Also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases?rq=1

Comment: and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84763/the-elephant-and-elephant-proper-and-common-noun?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You should give a proper reference to the book (author, title, date, page, etc), not just post an image. But this looks like a duplicate.

Comment: The book's name is High school English Grammar & Composition written by Wren & Martin first heading The Sentence